# intl extension installed but cant see in phpinfo()

Tags: php, linux, centos, intl, webmin

I am using centos 7 with lamp +webmin control panel php 7.2,I need intl intl extension,I followed few tutorials from google and intl extension is installed(I am sure because if I try to install again it says already installed latest updated )see bellow snnipest

`[root@xxxxxxx ~]# sudo yum --enablerepo=remi install php-intl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * Webmin: download.webmin.com
 * base: ftp.hosteurope.de
Excluding mirror: mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirror.alpix.eu
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirror.checkdomain.de
Excluding mirror: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
Excluding mirror: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * epel: ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de
 * extras: centos.mirror.iphh.net
 * remi: remi.mirror.liteserver.nl
 * remi-php56: remi.mirror.liteserver.nl
 * remi-php72: remi.mirror.liteserver.nl
 * remi-safe: remi.mirror.liteserver.nl
 * updates: ftp.hosteurope.de
Package php-intl-7.2.27-1.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

Already added `extension=php_intl` or `extension=intl` in both php.ini

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path     /etc/opt/rh/rh-php72
>
> Loaded Configuration File   /home/two4cloudspace/etc/php7.2/php.

and then restarted,but still I cant find intl extension in phpinfo() output
in my phpinfo() output showing my module directory is

> /opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules

but `php -r "echo ini_get('extension_dir');"` showing my module directory is

> /usr/lib64/php/modules

and I tried to find intl.so file in both directory and I found the file in

> /usr/lib64/php/modules

but cant find in

> /opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules

and then I downloaded the intl.so and uploaded to `/opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules` and restarted but still same issue.
if I command `php -m` I can see all modules and intl is included there.

but I cant find it in phpinfo() or where need to intl extension there it says intl missing
what am I doing wrong or how do I solve it?

Comment: Restart webserver.

Comment: already tried few times

Comment: Maybe you are having php-fpm as a different service?

Comment: I dont get your question, I am newbe on vps management it cames with  centos7+ lamp +webmin and then I installed php 7.2, can you describe your question a bit plz?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up different RPM packages providing PHP (run `rpm -qa | grep php | sort` and `rpm -qf $(which php)`, it will reveal before mentioned). The directory `/opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules` belongs to `rh-php72-php` and not to Remi. Thus `sudo yum install --enablerepo=centos-sclo-rh rh-php72-php-intl` helps if you need `/opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/intl.so`; don't forget to restart your webserver afterwards (if you don't use php-fpm rather mod_php).